# Booting from integrated RAID controller when another RAID controller is installed in a PCIe slot

Tags: raid, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a GA MA785GT UD3H motherboard with Windows Server 2008 R2 installed on a RAID1 using the on-board RAID controller.

I have now installed a RocketRaid 2680 controller and set up a RAID5 for all my data to be stored on.

Unfortunately I now cannot boot from the RAID1 anymore, the PC is trying to boot from the RAID5!

Does anyone have any experience of this motherboard / RAID controller combination?

Comment: Have you checked the System BIOS for the setting on which device you want to boot from first?

Comment: yes, I've set it to hard drive and disabled everything else, but it seems to want to boot from my RAID5. I've also tried putting the 2680 RAID controller at the bottom of the list, but to no avail.

Comment: From RocketRaid manual: "If you use a SCSI adapter to boot your system, you must make sure the RR2680/2684 controller BIOS will be loaded after that adapter’s BIOS. If not, try to move it to another PCI slot. Otherwise you may be unable to boot up your system."

Comment: hmm, I will give that a go tomorrow. But it'll mean using up my PCIe x16 slot. The RR2680 is currently in the PCIe x4 slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have this working, thanks to getting a response from Highpoint tech support. I had to turn off the BIOS in the RR2680 card. This is the response I got ...

> Hello,
>
> The procedure outlined below will
>   disable the RocketRAID card's Boot
>   functions, and BIOS display. To
>   re-enable these settings, simply
>   reflash cards' using the standard
>   procedure.
>
> Boot the system into pure DOS mode,
>   either from an optical drive (CD/DVD)
>   or floppy diskette.
>
> DOS images are available here:
>
> http://www.bootdisk.com
>
> We recommend the Win98SE versions
>   w/out RAMdisk if available - this copy
>   will work in just about any PC, and
>   quickly boots to a command prompt.
>
> Procedure:
>
> 1) Copy the load.exe and the BIOS
>   update file to the bootable floppy, or
>   burn them to the DOS CD image.
>
> 2) Boot the system to DOS mode.
>
> 3) At the command prompt, use the
>   following command line (a screen shot
>   is attached for reference):
>
> A:/>load -e 0=0 rrxxxx.xxx
>
> rrxxxx.xxx refers to the name of the
>   image file
>
> 4) After the successful flash, reboot
>   the system - the card's BIOS should no
>   longer be displayed during the
>   system's boot process.
>
> The card will remain fully functional,
>   at the operating system level. The Web
>   RAID management utilities will
>   recognize the card and disks (as will
>   the OS).
>
> Regards,
>
> Customer Support Department

I had to use an old shuttle PC (the only one I've got left with a floppy drive installed) to copy the files to an old boot disk I managed to find lying around.